# Meaning of square free values of polynomials over function fields

Tags: number-theory, field-theory

I'm learning about square free values, and specifically about square free values of polynomials over function fields.

My question is the following;

> What is meant by polynomials over function fields?

Earlier, I was studying square free values of polynomials over the integers, which made perfect sense to me. But now we're talking about function fields. Can anyone provide some analogy of text which will make this new concept clear for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enough information can be found here:

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/polynomials-over-a-field